# Java - Sorting Arraylist by an objects instances.

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, ranking

I've created a tournament ranking program which has two classes so far. A Team class and a Scoring class. The team class holds instance variables such as a elo score (double) based on win/loss/ties. The Scoring class takes an arraylist of Teams and the plan is to create a new Arraylist of teams in order from highest elo to lowest elo.

My question is, what would be the best way and how would I sort the teams based on elo ranking and add them to the new Arraylist.

Comment: Well, why don't you try something and see how it goes? There are a *lot* of sorting questions on SO, and I'm sure you'd be able to find something helpful without you needing someone to tell you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
class Scoring{

private ArrayList<Team> teams;



public void addTeams(ArrayList<Team> toAdd){

for(Team t : toAdd){
for(int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++){
if(teams.get(i).elo<t.elo)break;
}
teams.add(i, t);
}

}

}
```

Another way to do this, would be to create a comparitor, and sort the arraylist toAdd using that comparitor, then adding it to teams.

Comment: OP's asking for how to sort the list but you're not providing that in your answer. Also, you can use `List#addAll(Collection)` and remove all that code in the `addTeams` method.

Comment: Yes I am, the teams will all be entered in a sorted manner. As long as all teams are entered sorted, then the list will always be sorted.

Comment: You can use a `PriorityQueue` instead.

Comment: As for List#addAll(Collection) -- addTeams does not do that -_-

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza interesting. how so? EDIT: You just place the elo score as a priority. Yes so its very similar to what I did.

Comment: Read about it: [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Comment: Still, for priority queue, you would need a comparator.

Comment: Any sorting on custom objects needs a `Comparator` unless the class implements `Comparable`...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, anytime you sort you have a comparitor. However, in some cases, like this, you don't have to specify a comparitor in a seperate class -- the "comparitor" for my sorting above is teams.get(i).elo<t.elo. Note that it is not declared as an object itself. When I say "don't use a comparitor" I mean don't declare an instance of the Comparator class.